# Best practice: get URL parameter into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, url-routing

I have a web application and want to be able to pass an object ID via the URL:

```
www.example.com/?id=someObjectID
```

I then want to retrieve the Object data from the server (e.g. with an Ajax call).

What is best practice to handle this?

I came up with:

1. analyse the URL with JavaScript.

   pros:

   - everything is pure client side JS

   cons:

   - there is no standard way for URL parameter handling in JS
2. get the URL parameters server side and render them into the HTML response (e.g. inside a variable). Then make the ajax request client side.

   pros:

   - easy URL parameter handling server side (e.g. with express)

   cons:

   - parameter information makes a round trip to the server
   - server side rendering of the website (I could start render everything server side)

Are there any other options?

What are best practice here?

Is there any standard libraries/tools?

Comment: There is no best practice, it depends entirely on your situation. However, you shouldn't be making excess AJAX requests for no reason.

Comment: While it is true thee is no OOB solution to do it in Javascript, it's just a few lines function though, so better use it if you need/want to do it client-side. I see no big advantage doing it through querystrings if you act client-side through AJAX though